# Get countries and capitals from website Python

Tags: python, parsing, python-requests, python-re

I need get countries and capitals from [https://geographyfieldwork.com/WorldCapitalCities.htm](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) and create DataFrame with 2 columns: country, capital
With module 'requests'

I tried using the 're' module, but it didn't work(

Comment: What you are trying to do is called web scraping (extracting data from html) and with libraries like beautifulsoup it can be achieved. However for your use case you can fetch data from Rest APIs using requests module. Here's an API for your use case: https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries/capital

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also, you need to fix the link in your question. Clicking on it just takes me to the main stackoverflow page.

Answer (score 0):

Using [pd.read_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) which returns a list. The table you want is in index 2.

```
import pandas as pd


url = "https://geographyfieldwork.com/WorldCapitalCities.htm"
df = pd.read_html(url)[2]

print(df)
```